# index pages that only can find with search

Tags: seo, google-search-console, sitemap

I have a website that have 5 static pages and more than 700 dynamic contents that only can access them by search.
I create `sitemap.xml` that include 5 static pages and whole of dynamic contents.
But Google webmaster tools shows that Google only index static pages what do I must to do to index all pages.
In Google webmaster tools is wrote that 7xx page are submitted and 5 pages are indexed

Comment: You should fix the page problems first, you have metas outside the head tag.

Comment: Your dynamic page does not seem to contain much actual content? Is your `sitemap.xml` file located in the document root? If it is it is returning a 500 internal server error.